# ftp shell script breaks up after the lcd-command

Tags: shell, ftp, download

I created a shell script to download several files, all starting with "2014" from an ftp server. I use `mget` for this and the filename `2014*`.
To make sure that the files are saved at the right local place I use `lcd` before.

It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

HOST='ftpserver.name.de'
USER='user1'
PASSWD='pw1'
FILE='2014*'
LOCDIR='/home/local/data2014/'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
lcd $LOCDIR 
mget $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

when I try this, the script just runs:

```
lx9000: ftp_get.sh
Connected to ftpserver.name.de.
220 FTP-Server: ftpserver.name.de
331 Password required for user1
230 User user1 logged in
Local directory now: /home/local/data2014/
221 Goodbye.
```

why dose it stop before the downloading proceeds?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
prompt off
```

before the `mget`.

Comment: now I just get (after that stuff mentioned above):
Interactive mode off.
221 Goodbye.

Comment: Try adding "ls" above your "mget" line to see the names of the files on the FTP server. Then chose any file that is listed and change your script to just get the one file you have chosen and see what happens.

Comment: okay, I got my mistake: I wasn't in the right directory. I used "cd anotherfolder/" and than it works. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of assistance. Please consider accepting my answer if it helped so I get a lovely big green tick :-)